# Enable horizontal scroll for a row in winforms table layout

Tags: winforms, horizontal-scrolling, tablelayout

I have an user control with table layout which holds panels in each row. Table layout is docked to the form and panels are docked within each row. Within each panel I have docked table layout with multiple rows holding docked controls. All works fine.

I want to add a panel with grid view in a row of root layout.Grid will have more columns which doesn't fit in the panel view area and requires horizontal scroll. How to enable horizontal scroll only for a particular panel in one of table layout rows?

EDIT:
[image]

I want to add more columns to the grid in Details panel after the highlighted columns and enable horizontal scrolling only for the Details panel.

I am using Telerik controls in my form.

Comment: A picture of the layout would be helpful here.

Comment: @LarsTech, I have included an image of my layout in the original post as an edit.

Comment: The DataGridView (I assume that's what you mean by *grid view*) already shows scrollbars when the content doesn't fit in its viewport. Panels and most Containers can also auto-scroll, but I don't see the point here

Comment: Hi @Jimi, thanks for your comment. I am using Telerik gridview. Grid or panel shows vertical scroll automatically when rows added. But if I have to add more columns, the horizontal scroll is not coming. Rather i have to adjust the width of other columns to fit in new columns.

Comment: Well, I don't know the grid you're referring to (BTW, add the appropriate tags), but I really doubt it cannot show horizontal scrollbars, it would be abysmal design. Anyway, as mentioned, a Panel can be set to `AutoScroll` (it's a `ScrollableControl`, now assuming that by Panel you mean the default WinForms Panel Control and that *table layout* means a `TableLayoutPanel` - use proper names)